# Auction item in stash but not in inventory

Tags: diablo-iii

What if your bought item from the auction house is in your stash but no where to be found in my inventory. No my inventory is not full. Yes I clicked on send to stash in the completed tab. :)

Comment: It does say stash... so.... check there.

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference between your "stash" and "inventory."  The stash is shared between all characters (hardcore and regular characters each have their own stash), while each character's inventory is theirs alone.

If you go into your stash with one of your characters, you can drag or right click the item into the character's inventory

Answer (score 2):

If you sent it to your stash, it's.. well, in your stash. Go pick it up from your friendly stash treasure chest, available in any town in any Act on any difficulty.